# Is there an include_partial equivalent in Twig (symfony 2.0)?

Tags: symfony, twig

I really like to use partial templates in my symfony 1.4 projets and I was wondering if there is something like that with Twig in symfony 2.0.

It's way more clear and reusable to have something like that

```
<?php include_partial('forum/message', array('message'=>$message)); ?>
```

Rathen than a big portion of php/html code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. It's called `include` in Twig. Details are in the [docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html).